# How to save numbers in room database kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-room

I want to create a simple financial report app.

With opening balance, inventory purchase, other expenses, sales and banking all as double numbers I want to use room database, jetpack components

Comment: Please be specific with your question. If you are not sure where to start try a tutorial or sample code available online and answer any problem you face specifically.

Answer (score 0):

You can't ask this type of questions but look at this sample (simplest way to use roomDB)

First of all you need to define you database class

```
@Database(entities = [CompaniesModel::class,  UserPoint::class], version = 15) //here is the models which will have the structure of your database  
abstract class DataBase : RoomDatabase() {

/**
 * define companies dao to make some quires
 */
abstract fun homeDao(): HomeDao
abstract fun companiesDao(): CompaniesListDao

companion object {
    @Volatile
    private var databaseInstance: DataBase? = null

    fun getDatabaseInstance(mContext: Context): DataBase =
        databaseInstance ?: synchronized(this) {
            databaseInstance ?: buildDatabaseInstance(mContext).also {
                databaseInstance = it
            }
        }

    private fun buildDatabaseInstance(mContext: Context) =
        Room.databaseBuilder(mContext, DataBase::class.java, "crm")
            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
            .allowMainThreadQueries()
            .build()
    }
}
```

and the models which contain the structure of your database

```
@Entity(tableName = "companiesModel")
data class CompaniesModel(

@PrimaryKey
@ColumnInfo(name = "id")
@SerializedName("id")
var id: Int,
@ColumnInfo(name = "name")
@SerializedName("name")
var name: String,
@ColumnInfo(name = "image")
@SerializedName("image")
var image: String

)
```

and the Dao which have all your queres

```
@Dao
interface CompaniesListDao {
/**
 * this fun to insert data in room db after fetch data from server
 */
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun insertCompanies(contactModel: List<CompaniesModel>)

/**
 * this fun to get data from room db to make some caching in app
 */
@Query("SELECT * FROM companiesModel")
fun getCompaniesList(): List<CompaniesModel>

/**
 * this fun to clear companies list from room db
 */
@Query("DELETE FROM companiesModel")
fun clearCompaniesList()

@Update
fun update(contactModel: List<CompaniesModel>)
}
```

to access the data you should call it like this

```
DataBase.getDatabaseInstance(App.instance).companiesDao().something
```